# Custom Meta fields Update hook?

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks

HI Is there any hook available that we can add it into functions.php and fire only when "Custom meta fields gets edited" ? I really need this . If anyone with the knowledge , please help me.

Till now, I've discovered save_post hook but it only fires when post title field or Description fields gets edited. IN my case I've one custom post type "property" with so many custom meta fields with it. and I need to find some hook which works same as save_post but when custom fields gets edited.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is number of hooks in generic low level [`update_metadata()`](http://queryposts.com/function/update_metadata/) function. Limited to the post meta you would probably want to use `update_postmeta` or `updated_postmeta`.

Comment: Hi Rarst, thanks for the reply, I tried adding updated_postmeta, but unfortunately it is not firing when I update the custom meta fields value, and because of that I am not able to run my actions.

Answer (score 1):

[This hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/updated_(meta_type)_meta) `updated_{$meta_type}_meta` is called after a call to update_metadata succeeds.

```
<?php add_action( "updated_{$meta_type}_meta", $function_name', 10, 4 ); ?>
```

For example, to respond to updates to post metadata:

```
<?php
    add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'my_update_post_meta', 10, 4 );

    function my_update_post_meta($meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value) 
    {
        //do stuff
    }
```

?>